# Hold till last command completes its execution

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, bash, amazon-web-services, shell-scripting

I am developing a shell script which actually stops aws running instances in a particular region & start them again as a part of schedule maintenance. but as ec2-api tools are heavy, takes time to execute the ec2 command. I want my system to hold up till the last ec2 command executes entirely and show its O/P. Like if i am executing

ec2-stop-instances some-id --region us-west-1

It should wait for completion of execution of ec2-stop.  I didn't find any solution for this hence posting here.

Let me know if any one have any idea about how it should be done.

Comment: If the script just forks to the background then `wait` will probably do what you're looking for. But I think there some asynchronous magic in the script which isn't going to allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ec2-stop-instances` does not wait for the instance to stop.  It only tells AWS to stop instance.  It does not wait for the instance to actually stop.

After executing `ec2-stop-instances`, you will need to execute `ec2-describe-instances` repeatedly to get the current status and only when the status is 'stopped' would you continue with your script.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the hint. Really it was very helpful for me.